# Extracting audio from an .mp4 file on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a large mp4 file on AWS S3. Is there some way to download just the audio as an mp3 without download the entire mp4 file first and then extracting the audio?

Comment: You can try AWS Elemental MediaConvert.

Comment: There is also [Audio Support for the Amazon Elastic Transcoder | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/audio-support-for-the-amazon-elastic-transcoder/).